# Error getMap();

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I have an error in this line of code (72). I have already done a search in the forum but nothing solved yet, I tried to change to getMapAsync ();

It seems that this function is obsolete but as this code I found on the internet I do not know how to update it.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
    double mLatitude = 0;
    double mLongitude = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Initializing
            mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
            mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

            // Setting onclick event listener for the map
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Already map contain destination location
                    if(mMarkerPoints.size()>1){

                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        mMarkerPoints.clear();
                        mGoogleMap.clear();
                        LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                        drawMarker(startPoint);
                    }

                    drawMarker(point);

                    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                    if(mMarkerPoints.size() >= 2){
                        LatLng origin = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                        LatLng dest = mMarkerPoints.get(1);

                        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Sensor enabled

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }



    /** A class to download data from Google Directions URL */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }


    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        mMarkerPoints.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        /**
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
         * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        if(mMarkerPoints.size()==1){
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        }else if(mMarkerPoints.size()==2){
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }

        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
        if(mMarkerPoints.size() < 2){

            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));

            drawMarker(point);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the map instantiation isn't finished when running the `onCreate`. You have to start your tasks depending on the map when you received the callback that the `Map` is done loading.

Comment: It can exemplify where I should change I'm new to android.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get map async, something like that:

```
public class FindLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
            OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap map;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_location);

            SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            this.map = map;
            //from this moment do whatever you want to do with map
        }
    }
```

You are getting error probably becouse map is not ready when you call *getMap()* and you get null. To prevent it, you shold always get map async, and when it's ready, make some operations on it.